# Scrollview of images not working inside custom table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have 2 images (as of right now) being downloaded from Parse to their corresponding cellForRowAtIndexPath. I'm trying to put these images within a UIScrollView.

**Testing if Images are there:** 
The images are being downloaded correctly because I set up 2 UIImageViews and both of the images from Parse were displayed correctly throughout the indexPaths

**Test scrollView:** then I also, created to an array of preloaded images (5 images) from my desktop and put them in an array within tableViewCell. They showed up correctly throughout my indexPaths and I was able to scroll through my 5 images.

Latest thing I tried.

After the 5 images I tried from my desktop I figured just to use an array of UIImages which will be passed from my ViewController's.

ViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//...previous code
resultsHasImageOneFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
(ImageOneData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        myImages.append(UIImage(data: ImageOneData!)) //adds to array in cell
    }
 }

resultsImageTwoFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {    (ImageTwoData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

    myImages.append(UIImage(data: ImageTwoData!)) //adds to array in cell

    }
//...additional code: including returning cell
}
```

Custom TableViewCell:
I plan to add up to 5 images that could be retrieved from Parse that's why I'm doing this for-in loop.

```
@IBOutlet var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageWidth: CGFloat = 310
var imageHeight: CGFloat = 400
var yPosition: CGFloat = 0
var xPosition: CGFloat = 0
var scrollViewContentSize: CGFloat = 0

var myImages: [UIImage?] = [] //will hold 2 images per row

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let theWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    //create add UIImageView to scrollView
    for var index = 0; index < myImages.count; index++ {

        var myImage: UIImage = myImages[index]!

        var myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = myImage

        myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
        myImageView.frame.origin.y = 0

        imageScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

        xPosition += imageWidth
        scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth //imageHeight

        imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)

    }
}
```

I've printed out the count for the array and it says it's empty...

I have also tried the scrollView code in my ViewController and it still did not show anything. What am I missing? this is really annoying me.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let theWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    //create add UIImageView to scrollView
if(index>0)
{
    for var index = 0; index < myImages.count; index++ {

        var myImage: UIImage = myImages[index]!

        var myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = myImage

        myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
        myImageView.frame.origin.y = 0

        imageScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

        xPosition += imageWidth
        scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth //imageHeight

        imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)
}
}
```

Conditions

- just check the condition if index is empty or not,because if u get the images from server side its took time.
- otherwise call the scrollview method after you get the image details.